# for rest kit RKObjectMapping file not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, restkit

I have xcode version 6.4 ,ios sdk version 8.4 and mac yosemite 10.10 when i installled cocoapod for restkit. After running version it is showing error RKObjectMapping.h file not found

Comment: please search for duplicates of this question

Comment: i tried all the answers of duplicate of this question but still not getting solution

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to add `${PODS_ROOT}` (and set it to recursive) in `Header Seach Paths` under `Build Settings` in your target settings.